# How to handle flows migration to handle contract upgrade?

Tags: corda

What's the best way to maintain/approach contract upgrade of states in terms of flows.

Scenario.
Existing BondStateV1
and the flows are using class type of BondStateV1 i.e `queryBy<BondStateV1>`

Now. We want to upgrade BondStateV1 to BondStateV2.
How do we change the flows?

1. Do we keep the old flows, and deploy a new FlowCordappV2?
2. Or after migrating BondStateV1 to BondStateV2, do we deprecate/delete all the old FlowCordapp, refactor to handle V2 and redeploy?

Answer (score 0):

State and contract upgrades happen independently of flows, by following the approach given here: https://docs.corda.net/upgrading-cordapps.html#contract-and-state-versioning.

But your flow will then need to handle the (potential) presence of both `BondStateV1` and `BondStateV2` states on the network. You can achieve this by following the instructions here: https://docs.corda.net/upgrading-cordapps.html#how-do-i-upgrade-my-flows.